# What is the most elegant way to evaluate sport game estimates in Python?

Tags: python

I want to evaluate estimates on sport games - in my case football (i.e. soccer) games. I want to use Python for this.

Basically, there is always a `team_home` result, a `team_away` result, an `estimate_home`and `estimate_away`. For example, a game ended `1:0` and the estimate was `0:0` - this would return `wrong`.

There are only four possible cases and outcomes:

1. `wrong` as in the case above
2. `tendency` estimate of the winner was right, but not the goal difference (e.g. `3:0`)
3. `goal difference` for the right goal difference, such as `2:1`
4. `right` for the exact right estimate

What is the most elegant way to process estimates and results in Python?

Comment: Is this our homework? Come on, show some effort.

Comment: I'm missing context: depending on what do you want to do with the results I would . If these are betting results with differences on returns (eg x return if you have the win right, y return if you have the goal difference right, z return if you have it exactly right) and you want to optimize a strategy + have a large dataset, numpy or pandas would be a much better fit for instance?

Comment: @Carst The script will be part of a bet application. It will have many players (at the beginning around 20) who will bet on football games every week. These bets shall get evaluated in the way described and return points - right=3, goal difference=2, tendency=1, wrong=0. Hence there are 9 games a week with 20x8 bets a week that need to get evaluated.

Comment: Thanks! Then I think you will be better off with something else (Pandas) as that will greatly help you to solve other, subsequent questions. I'll write an answer

Comment: I can't really understand why it's labeled off-topic. If you want I can include my attempted solutions which I added as a first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would urge you to think a bit about what kind of questions will you have? i.e.

- Do you want to report per player a list of his estimations vs actuals?
- Do you want to rank players?
- Do you want to do more statistical stuff? (player x is better in estimating games where team y is involved)

I will assume you want to do at the very least the first two!

I've tried to make the code readable/simple but in many ways it's much more complicated than the other answers, yet it also gives you a whole toolbox of things that you can do with it and handle large amounts of data really quickly. So just see it as another option :)

Basically with pandas you can also do more statistical stuff in the future when you want to. But realistically, those kind of questions really influence the answer to your question (or rather: the best fit of the answers here).

I assume you have a database (relational / mongodb / whatever), I'm faking it a bit here by adding lists. Even though I'm using pandas here, most of the things described there you could also do in a relational database in a really easy way. But pandas rocks ;) so this will work fine too. If you do something with friends with excel or csv files you can also import those directly using pandas read_csv or read_xls

```
import pandas as pd

# game is a unique id (like a combination of date, home_team and away_team)
bet_list = [
    {'playerid': 1, 'game': 1, 'date': 1, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 3, 'away_goals': 5},
    {'playerid': 2, 'game': 1, 'date': 1, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 2, 'away_goals': 1},
    {'playerid': 3, 'game': 1, 'date': 1, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 1, 'away_goals': 0},
    {'playerid': 4, 'game': 1, 'date': 1, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 0, 'away_goals': 0},
    {'playerid': 1, 'game': 2, 'date': 2, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 3, 'away_goals': 5},
    {'playerid': 2, 'game': 2, 'date': 2, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 2, 'away_goals': 1},
    {'playerid': 3, 'game': 2, 'date': 2, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 1, 'away_goals': 0},
    {'playerid': 4, 'game': 2, 'date': 2, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 0, 'away_goals': 0},   
    {'playerid': 1, 'game': 3, 'date': 3, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 3, 'away_goals': 5},
    {'playerid': 2, 'game': 3, 'date': 3, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 2, 'away_goals': 1},
    {'playerid': 3, 'game': 3, 'date': 3, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 1, 'away_goals': 0},
    {'playerid': 4, 'game': 3, 'date': 3, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 0, 'away_goals': 0}  
]

result_list = [
    {'game': 1, 'date': 1, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 3, 'away_goals': 4},
    {'game': 2, 'date': 2, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 2, 'away_goals': 2},
    {'game': 3, 'date': 3, 'home_team': 'Bayern', 'away_team': 'VfL', 'home_goals': 0, 'away_goals': 0},
]

def calculate_result(input_df):
    input_df['result'] = 0
    # home wins (result 1)
    mask = input_df['home_goals'] > input_df['away_goals']
    input_df['result'][mask] = 1
    # away wins (result 2)
    mask = input_df['home_goals'] < input_df['away_goals']
    input_df['result'][mask] = 2
    # draws (result 3)
    mask = input_df['home_goals'] == input_df['away_goals']
    input_df['result'][mask] = 3
    # goal difference
    input_df['goal_difference'] = input_df['home_goals'] - input_df['away_goals']
    return input_df

# so what where the expectations?
bet_df = pd.DataFrame(bet_list)
bet_df = calculate_result(bet_df)
# if you want to look at the results
bet_df

# what were the actuals
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_list)
result_df = calculate_result(result_df)
# if you want to look at the results
result_df

# now let's compare them!
# i take a subsetof the result df and link results on the game
combi_df = pd.merge(left=bet_df, right=result_df[['game', 'home_goals', 'away_goals', 'result', 'goal_difference']], left_on='game', right_on='game', how='inner', suffixes=['_bet', '_actual'])
# look at the data
combi_df

def calculate_bet_score(input_df):
    '''
Notice that I'm keeping in extra columns, because those are nice for comparative analytics in the future. Think: "you had this right, just like x% of all the people"

    '''
    input_df['bet_score'] = 0
    # now look at where people have correctly predicted the result
    input_df['result_estimation'] = 0
    mask = input_df['result_bet'] == input_df['result_actual']
    input_df['result_estimation'][mask] = 1 # correct result
    input_df['bet_score'][mask] = 1 # bet score for a correct result
    # now look at where people have correctly predicted the difference in goals when they already predicted the result correctly
    input_df['goal_difference_estimation'] = 0
    bet_mask = input_df['bet_score'] == 1
    score_mask = input_df['goal_difference_bet'] == input_df['goal_difference_actual']
    input_df['goal_difference_estimation'][(bet_mask) & (score_mask)] = 1 # correct result
    input_df['bet_score'][(bet_mask) & (score_mask)] = 2 # bet score for a correct result
    # now look at where people have correctly predicted the exact goals
    input_df['goal_exact_estimation'] = 0
    bet_mask = input_df['bet_score'] == 2
    home_mask = input_df['home_goals_bet'] == input_df['home_goals_actual']
    away_mask = input_df['away_goals_bet'] == input_df['away_goals_actual']
    input_df['goal_exact_estimation'][(bet_mask) & (home_mask) & (away_mask)] = 1 # correct result
    input_df['bet_score'][(bet_mask)  & (home_mask) & (away_mask)] = 3 # bet score for a correct result
    return input_df

combi_df = calculate_bet_score(combi_df)

# now look at the results
combi_df

# and you can do nifty stuff like making a top player list like this:
combi_df.groupby('playerid')['bet_score'].sum().order(ascending=False)
# player 4 is way ahead!
# which game was the best estimated game?
combi_df.groupby('game')['bet_score'].mean().order(ascending=False)
# game 3! though abysmal predictions in general ;)
```

As I said, it's mostly to give a different view / idea of possibilities of data manipulation in Python. Once you're getting serious with large amounts of data, this (vector/numpy/pandas-based) approach will be the quickest, but you have to ask yourself what logic you want to do inside the database and outside of it, etc.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Splendid answer! This gives me plenty of things to think about and shows me how to structure an app that can scale (especially when it comes to statistical analysis)! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Another answer, that reflects my opinion about *elegance* (a rather subjective parameter, I agree). I would like to have my objects defined by classes, built with [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) in mind, and with an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that manages the relationships among objects. This brings many advantages and more clear code.

I'm using [pony ORM](http://ponyorm.com/) here, but there are many other excellent options (and with more permissive license, eventually) like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or [Django's ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/overview/).

**here is a complete example** -  first we define the models:

```
from pony.orm import *

class Player(db.Entity):
    """A player is somebody who place a bet, identified by its name."""
    name = Required(unicode)
    score = Required(int, default=0)
    bets = Set('Bet', reverse='player')
    # any other player's info can be stored here


class Match(db.Entity):
    """A Match is a game, played or not yet played."""

    ended = Required(bool, default=False)
    home_score = Required(int, default=0)
    visitors_score = Required(int, default=0)

    bets = Set('Bet', reverse='match')


class Bet(db.Entity):
    """A class that stores a bet for a specific game"""

    match = Required(Match, reverse="bets")
    home_score = Required(int, default=0)
    visitors_score = Required(int, default=0)
    player = Required(Player, reverse="bets")

@db_session
def calculate_wins(match):
    bets = select(b for b in Bet if b.match == match)[:]
    for bet in bets:
        if (match.home_score == bet.home_score) and (match.visitors_score == bet.visitors_score):
            bet.player.score += 3  # exact
        elif (match.home_score - match.visitors_score) == (bet.home_score - bet.visitors_score):
            bet.player.score += 2  # goal differences
        elif ((match.home_score > match.visitors_score) == (bet.home_score > bet.visitors_score)) and \
           (match.home_score != match.visitors_score) and (bet.home_score != bet.visitors_score):
            bet.player.score += 1  # tendency
        else:
            bet.player.score += 0  # wrong
```

with these classes you can create and update your matches, players, bets database.
if you want statistics and data aggregation/sorting you can query the database according to your needs.

```
db = Database('sqlite', ':memory:')  # you may store it on a file if you like
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

player1 = Player(name='furins')
player2 = Player(name='Martin')

match1 = Match()

furins_bet = Bet(match=match1, player=player1, home_score=0, visitors_score=0)
martin_bet = Bet(match=match1, player=player2, home_score=3, visitors_score=0)


# the game begins ...
match1.home_score = 1
match1.visitors_score = 0
# the game ended ...
match1.ended = True

commit() #let's update the database


calculate_wins(match1)

print("furins score: %d"%(player1.score)) # returns 0
print("Martin score: %d"%(player2.score)) # returns 1
```

you may eventually even integrate very complex data analysis of time series using numpy, if you like, as Carst suggested, but I believe that these additions -albeit very interesting- are a little bit OT with regard of your original question.

Comment: I really like this answer too! It's great from a functionality perspective. I think my answer is more focused on the reporting/analytics side (and calculations you would do there).
Would be nice to combine them :)

Comment: I agree, the two answers complements in building a more complete set of functions and approaches to the problem. Now it's up to Martin to decide what are the precise requirements of the final application and pick the best from both (or from future answers). Thanks Carst ;)

Comment: Very hard choice for me. Both answers are excellent and put a focus on different things. I will try to work on both of them and share my results here again...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete albeit not very elegant solution:

```
def evaluation(team_home, team_away, estimate_home, estimate_away):
    delta_result = team_home - team_away
    delta_estimate = estimate_home - estimate_away

    if delta_result == delta_estimate:
        if team_home != estimate_home:
            print "goal difference"
        else:
            print "right"
    elif delta_result > 0 and delta_estimate > 0:
        print "tendency"
    elif delta_result < 0 and delta_estimate < 0:
        print "tendency"
    else:
        print "wrong"

evaluation(2, 1, 2, 1)  # right
evaluation(2, 1, 1, 0)  # goal difference
evaluation(2, 1, 3, 0)  # tendency
evaluation(2, 1, 0, 0)  # wrong

evaluation(2, 2, 2, 2)  # right
evaluation(2, 2, 1, 1)  # goal difference
evaluation(2, 2, 0, 0)  # goal difference
evaluation(2, 2, 1, 0)  # wrong

evaluation(0, 1, 0, 1)  # right
evaluation(0, 1, 1, 2)  # goal difference
evaluation(0, 1, 0, 2)  # tendency
evaluation(0, 1, 0, 0)  # wrong
```

Comment: there is an error in your code: evaluation(2,1,1,2) returns `goal difference` instead of `wrong`;

Comment: Yes, it does not cover the case where the result is an inverted estimation.

Comment: Now it is working for all cases. I just removed abs().

Comment: there is still an error. `evaluation(1,2,0,2)` now returns `wrong` instead of `tendency`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a more compact, and more symmetrical function. Is this what you mean for "elegant"?

```
def evaluate(team_home, team_away, estimate_home, estimate_away):
    if (team_home == estimate_home) and (team_away == estimate_away):
        return 'right'
    if (team_home - team_away) == (estimate_home - estimate_away):
        return 'goal difference'
    if ((team_home > team_away) == (estimate_home > estimate_away)) and \
       (team_home != team_away) and (estimate_home != estimate_away):
        return 'tendency'
    return 'wrong'
```

Comment: There is one case missing here as well for team_home < team_away, such as result `1:2` and estimation `0:3`.

Comment: no, it is not missing :) it is taken in account here: `if (team_home > team_away) == (estimate_home > estimate_away): return 'tendency'` -- it's just less intuitive since it translates in something like `if (false) == (false): return 'tendency'` that is `true`.

Comment: Okay, I can test it but cannot really understand the logic behind it. Doesn't it mean: If team_home is larger than team_away and estimate_home is larger than estimate_away, then return tendency. Where and how does the opposite result (team_home smaller than team_away) come into place here?

Comment: see my edited comment above. I already excluded the two team have the same number of goals in the "goal difference" case. Then if we are in the tendency case, the only two possible options are team_home is > than team_away or team_home is < than team_away. But if the tendency estimation is correct, than also estimate_home will be > than estimate_away in the first case (then you get `(true == true)`) and estimate_home will be < estimate_away in the second case (then you get `(false == false)`). In both cases the function returns `'tendency'` since also `(false == false)` returns `true`!

Comment: the point is I'm not saying "If `team_home` is larger than `team_away` **and** `estimate_home` is larger than `estimate_away`" but "If `team_home` is larger than `team_away` **in the same way as** `estimate_home` is larger than `estimate_away`". If it is still unclear (my English is poor) we may start a short chat about that if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will read through this as long as I'll understand it. No need for a chat, this thing is called learning ;-)

Comment: I've edited my answer to take in account the case `evaluation(0,1,0,0)`. My previous answer was not correct in that case (it returned 'tendency' instead of 'wrong'). Now it should be complete.